# Custom symbology on Geojson tileset in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, arcgis, mapbox-gl-js

I have this shapefile I created in QGIS that looks at US aquifers. 
[image: US Aquifers]

I really like the color scheme, and want to be able to display it as a tiled map via mapbox.

In QGIS, when I export the file as a geojson and upload it to Mapbox Studio, calling the file gives me this output (no styling, everything is just brown). [image]This makes sense because a geojson does not allow for custom symbology on a Field in a shapefile.

**Does mapbox have a way to allow for custom editing of layers in a geojson?** I cannot upload the .geojson as a "dataset" in mapbox because it is 20mb and the max file size mapbox allows is 5mb. So I have it loaded as a tileset.

Here is the code I am using to load up the geojson via the tileset that I have hosted on mapbox.

> ```
> map.on('load', function() {       
>   map.addLayer({
>             "id": "Aquifers",
>             "type": "fill",
>             "source": {
>                 type: 'vector',
>                 url: 'mapbox://myname.12cjkh1w'
>               },
>             'source-layer': 'aquifers-aidq86',
>             'minzoom':5,
>             "paint": {
>               "fill-color": "#e6a72e",
>               "fill-opacity": 1
>             }
>         });
> });
> ```

Comment: You can use Mapbox Studio https://mapbox.com/studio/ to create a new map style with your stylised data.

Comment: Why don't you upload as shapefile?

Comment: thanks both of you. Both options are valid, however I am using code that lets me toggle multiple layers on and off (seen here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/). So when I use Mapbox Studio or upload a Shapefiles, despite being able to edit them in Mapbox as a style or a tileset, I cannot call them with map.addLayer() which is what I need to be able to toggle them on and off.